# Inline block with dynamic height not aligned to the top

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `inline-block` elements sitting side-by-side acting as columns. The first column changes height because I add contents to it.

My problem now is that the second column follows the bottom of the expanding first column since both are `inline-block`. I want the second column to stick to the top and not follow the bottom of the other element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uompg/txLvuqbr/)

```js
$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>").appendTo($("#dynamic"));
});
```

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #dadada;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col" id="dynamic">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <p><a href="#">Click me</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline`, so change it to `top`.

```js
$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>").appendTo($("#dynamic"));
});
```

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #dadada;
  vertical-align: top; /*added*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col" id="dynamic">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <p><a href="#">Click me</a>
  </p>
</div>
```